# How to add a shortcut to toggle between `All` and `Folder` filter in everything?

Tags: everything

I have look over https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/keyboard_shortcuts/

No built-in .

In Everything, from the Tools menu, click Options.
Click the Keyboard tab.
There is no such option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu > Search > Organize Filters... (Ctrl+Shift+F)

In Organize Filters dialog-box select `Folder` > Edit...
In Edit Filter dialog-box at bottom you have `Keyboard shortcut:`
This will let you the toggling you asked for.